# Install mysql with puppet on vagrant vm

Tags: mysql, vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to install mysql server on a vagrant vm with puppet ,I've added  this line on the Vagrant file

```
config.vm.provision "puppet"
```

in the same Vagrantfile folder I've created the manifests folder and inside it folder  it's default.pp with this content

```
class { '::mysql::server':
  root_password           => 'root',
  remove_default_accounts => false,
  override_options        => $override_options
}
mysql::db { 'wordpress':
  user     => 'wordpress',
  password => '12345',
  host     => 'localhost',
  grant    => ['ALL'],
}
```

But I get this error message when I execute `vagrant provision`

```
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Warning: Setting templatedir is deprecated. See http://links.puppetlabs.com/env-settings-deprecations
==> default:    (at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:1139:in `issue_deprecation_warning')
==> default: Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class ::mysql::server at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-a11d1078b1b1f2e3bdea27312f6ba513/default.pp:5 on node vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.hitronhub.home
==> default: Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class ::mysql::server at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-a11d1078b1b1f2e3bdea27312f6ba513/default.pp:5 on node vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.hitronhub.home
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`puppetlabs-mysql`](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql) is a puppet module, which means it is not included with the base puppet executable. To use it, you'll need to do a few things:

1. Create a `modules` directory in your project for holding puppet modules
2. Use `puppet module install --modulepath modules puppetlabs-mysql` to install the MySQL module into the modules directory
3. [Configure `module_path` for the puppet provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html) in your Vagrantfile

Comment: I have to install  `puppet module install --modulepath modules puppetlabs-mysql` inthe guest  in the host??

Comment: You want to do it on the host before you create the vm, but if you do it later you can always run `vagrant provision` to redo the puppet apply,