# Get Puppet Modules for Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I have vagrant working and I just want to do this:

```
include 'stdlib'

file_line { 'ssh_key_server1' :
        path => '/home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys',
        line => 'ssh-rsa AAAA
}
```

It complains about the stdlib module.  So, I googled all over to solve it and found a post that recommended this:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib.git modules/stdlib
```

It copied the module source code from git but didn't seem to compile and vagrant won't compile it for me when I do a `vagrant provision`.  How do I compile?

I also tried using something called librarian puppet.  It seemed to want puppet installed on my host machine.  Please don't make me do that.  Is there another way?

Comment: If you downvote, you should comment!

Comment: First I didn't downvote your question.  For your question, you may look the solution with `librarian-puppet`. Oh, you have tried it, then you can ignore my comments

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install mysql with puppet on vagrant vm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142869/install-mysql-with-puppet-on-vagrant-vm)

Comment: Interesting issue, but I have to wonder: why use `file_line` over `ssh_authorized_key` here?